# Do I need to use clearInterval() when a React component is unmounted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval, clearinterval

What's up guys, I'm new to React so i met this code

```
const KeywordCycler = () => {

  const [isIntervalActive, setIsIntervalActive] = useState(false);
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState('');

  const keywords = ["word 1", "word 2", "word 3"];

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => (prevIndex + 1) % keywords.length);
    }, 1500);

    setIsIntervalActive(true);

    // Clean up the interval when the component is unmounted
    return () => {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      setIsIntervalActive(false);

    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setKeyword(keywords[currentIndex]);
  }, [currentIndex, keywords]);

  return <div id="keyword">
    {keyword}
    <h1>Interval Status: {isIntervalActive ? console.log('Active') : console.log('Inactive')}</h1>

  </div>;
};
```

```
function App() {
  const [showHome, setShowHome] = useState(true);


  const toggleHome = () => {

    return setShowHome(!showHome);
  }
  return (

    <>
      {showHome && <KeywordCycler />}
      <button onClick={toggleHome}>Toggle Home</button>
    </>

  );
}
```

The **`KeywordCycler`** component sets up an interval to cycle through an array of keywords and display one at a time. It uses state variables to track the interval status, current index, and displayed keyword. The interval starts when the component mounts and stops when it unmounts. The displayed keyword is updated based on the current index. The **`App`** component renders the **`KeywordCycler`** component conditionally and includes a button to toggle its visibility.

In this code, clicking the "Toggle Home" button causes the component to unmount, which stops the **`setInterval`** function due to the cleanup performed by **`clearInterval`**. However, when the **`clearInterval`** function is removed, the **`setInterval`** function still stops correctly when i click "Toggle Home", and no messages are logged to the console, so does that mean i don't have to use `clearInterval` in this case?

Comment: If the `clearInterval` is not called, the code does not error. But it also does not stop. It will also keep all related objects in memory. Try placing a `console.log` inside the interval function.

Comment: Do not use `useEffect(() => { setKeyword(keywords[currentIndex]); }, [currentIndex, keywords]);` - just do `const keyword = keywords[currentIndex];`.

Comment: There's a bug with your interval effect, it does not handle when `keywords.length` changes. It just keeps using the `keywords` value from when the effect started and `setInterval` was called. Solution 1: add `keywords.length` to the effect's dependency array. Solution 2: just keep increasing the index forever, do the `% keywords.length` only when computing the current `keyword`.

Comment: @Bergi 
1- do you mean because it's already gonna change the current index in the setInterval so no need to use useState?


2- I didn't get the second answer tbh so could explain it more please? and thank you

Comment: Yes. `currentIndex` is already state that changes, so https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#updating-state-based-on-props-or-state applies

Comment: Re 2), I missed that `keywords` is actually a `const` and not dynamic (part of state or props). You should however then ideally declare the constant outside of the component function, and you won't need to use it in a dependency array (of the `useEffect` that you don't need anyway).